# Double integration problem. Am I setting this up wrong?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$\iint_D xy dA$$ where $D$ is the region bounded by the line $y = x - 1$ and the parabola $y^2 = 2x + 6$. EValuate from left to right is the hint.

I drew this picture:

[image]

I set up my double integral this way:

$$\int_{-1}^5 \int_{-2}^{4} (y+1)(y) dydx$$

I think that's wrong but I'm not sure why.

I am told the right way to set this up is:

$$\int_{-2}^{4} \int_{(y^2-6)/2}^{1+y}xydxdy$$ is the right way to set this up but I'm not sure why. CAn someone visually explain?

Comment: The integrand should just be dxdy. limits look right after the edit. Picture it as horizontal strips within the bounded area... starting from y=-2 to y=4.

Answer (score 1):

Yoy need to set up the limits using the equations of the functions.  Using your picture the $x$ integral is $\frac{y^2-6}{2}$ to $y+1$, then the $y$ integral $-2$ to $4$.  Your limits are for a rectangle.

Comment: How can I know this? What's the intuition behind this? I edited my question btw

Comment: In the insdie integral, when integration with respect to dx... why are the limits in terms of y? @herb steinberg

Comment: @Jwan622, the outside integral is in terms of y. So we're starting at the bottom at y=-2 and going up to 4. At each y value, we need a horizontal strip of area between the two curves. What is the horizontal length of the strip at a particular y-value?

Comment: The difference between the left and right curves which is the distance from the parabola to the line right? I see... Why can't we do this with dy as the inner one? Is it because there's a portion of the integral that starts and ends from the same parabola if we do this with relation to dy as the inner integral?

Comment: If the outer is from -2 to 4, the horizontal strip is the difference between the parabola and the line right?

Comment: That's right. It's just the difference between the parabola and the line.

Comment: You can use dy as the inner integral... and use vertical strips. But it is more complicated. Start at x=-3 and go to x=5. Look at the vertical strips... the problem is from -3 to -1, the vertical strip goes from the parabola to itself. Then from from -1 to 5 the vertical strip goes from the line to the parabola. So you'll need to split the integral into two parts.